# Calculating visible area in infinite webpage

Tags: javascript, panzoom

I'm using [@panzoom/panzoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@panzoom/panzoom) package for creating infinite webpage where I have items placed on it. When user pans I need to lazyload items based on their x and y coordinates. To achieve lazyload of items I need to calculate visible area on the screen.

Working example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-brown-pd3nye?file=/App.svelte)

```
const lazyload = e => {
    if (!panzoomInstance || !panzoomElem) return false;

    const scale = panzoomInstance.getScale();
    const pan = panzoomInstance.getPan();
    const { width, height } = document
      .getElementById("container")
      .getBoundingClientRect();

    const x1 = (0 - pan.x) / scale;
    const y1 = (0 - pan.y) / scale;
    const x2 = (width - pan.x) / scale;
    const y2 = (height - pan.y) / scale;

    const visibleArea = {
      x1: Math.floor(x1 * scale),
      y1: Math.floor(y1 * scale),
      x2: Math.floor(x2 * scale),
      y2: Math.floor(y2 * scale)
    };

    const itemsToLoad = items.filter(
      i =>
        i.x >= visibleArea.x1 &&
        i.x <= visibleArea.x2 &&
        i.y >= visibleArea.y1 &&
        i.y <= visibleArea.y2
    );

    console.log(`scale ${scale}`);
    console.log(`pan ${JSON.stringify(pan)}`);
    console.log("visibleArea", visibleArea);

    itemsToLoad.map(i => console.log(i.x, i.y));

    console.log(`found ${itemsToLoad.length} \n\n`);
};
```

**Issue:** Above calculation for getting visible area works fine when the scale is >= 1. Anything less than one will result in wrong calculation meaning the x and y coords I'm getting does not cover entire visible area.

Comment: Checkout this documentation which purpose is exactely to solve this kind of problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: @Peterrabbit Yes I looked into Intersection Observer earlier. I cannot use it because this requires me to query all the items in advance and then wrap it with intersection observer. What I'm looking for is a way to fetch items only when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, two things you need to fix;

1. The pan object — `panzoomInstance.getPan()` seems to return incorrect values somehow. Change that to `document.getElementById("panzoom-container").getBoundingClientRect()` like you did for the container.
2. You are dividing xi and yi values by **scale** then multiplying with scale again, it won't change anything. Zooming out (means visible area increases) makes our scale factor smaller, so dividing the bounding area of our container by a smaller value makes the area bigger and for zooming in (means visible area decreases) makes our scale factor bigger, so dividing the bounding area of our container by a bigger value makes the area smaller. So, we need to remove the multiplying parts.

Changes should look like this.

```js
const { top: panTop, left: panLeft } = document
  .getElementById("panzoom-container")
  .getBoundingClientRect();

const x1 = (0 - panLeft) / scale;
const y1 = (0 - panTop) / scale;
const x2 = (width - panLeft) / scale;
const y2 = (height - panTop) / scale;

const visibleArea = {x1, y1, x2, y2};
```

Secondly, you are only checking the **top-left** corner of each element. If the top-left corner is not visible, then the element itself is also not visible. This computation seems incorrect to me. Instead, using the intersection percent would be more accurate. However, if we want to check the intersection percent, we need to know the **width** and **height** properties of each element we have. If you're able to pass these properties along with the x and y properties that are already being passed, the code below should work perfectly. But if not, and you are okay with checking only the top-left corner, use the fix above.

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-76091260-kmjuif?file=/App.svelte)

```js
const lazyload = e => {
  if (!panzoomInstance || !panzoomElem) return false;

  const {
    width: containerWidth,
    height: containerHeight
  } = document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect();

  const { top: panTop, left: panLeft } = document
    .getElementById("panzoom-container")
    .getBoundingClientRect();

  const scale = panzoomInstance.getScale();

  const itemsToLoad = items.filter(i => {
    let bounding = {
      top: i.y * scale + panTop,
      left: i.x * scale + panLeft,
      right: (i.x + i.width) * scale + panLeft, // necessary for intersectionPercent
      bottom: (i.y + i.height) * scale + panTop // necessary for intersectionPercent
    };

    let intersection = intersectionPercent(
      { top: 0, left: 0, right: containerWidth, bottom: containerHeight },
      bounding
    );

    if (intersection > 0) { // use >= 0.5 for at least 50% intersection ratio
      console.log(i.id + " => " + intersection * 100 + "%");
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
  console.log(`found ${itemsToLoad.length} item(s) intersecting. \n`);
  console.log(itemsToLoad);
};

function intersectionPercent(a, b) {
  let i = {
    left: Math.max(a.left, b.left),
    right: Math.min(a.right, b.right),
    top: Math.max(a.top, b.top),
    bottom: Math.min(a.bottom, b.bottom)
  };

  if (i.left < i.right && i.top < i.bottom) {
    return (
      ((i.right - i.left) * (i.bottom - i.top)) /
      ((b.right - b.left) * (b.bottom - b.top))
    );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I also added some CSS reset to the `index.html` file for annoying margin, padding, or box-sizing problems.

Comment: This solution is great, Thank you @İlyas Bilgihan

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
  const lazyload = e => {
    if (!panzoomInstance || !panzoomElem) return false;

    const scale = panzoomInstance.getScale();
    const pan = panzoomInstance.getPan();

    const { width, height } = document
      .getElementById("container")
      .getBoundingClientRect();

    const x1 = -pan.x - (width / scale - width) / 2;
    const y1 = -pan.y - (height / scale - height) / 2;
    const x2 = x1 + width / scale;
    const y2 = y1 + height / scale;

    const visibleArea = {
      x1: Math.floor(x1),
      y1: Math.floor(y1),
      x2: Math.floor(x2),
      y2: Math.floor(y2)
    };

    const itemsToLoad = items.filter(
      i =>
        i.x >= visibleArea.x1 &&
        i.x <= visibleArea.x2 &&
        i.y >= visibleArea.y1 &&
        i.y <= visibleArea.y2
    );

    console.log("visibleArea", visibleArea);

    itemsToLoad.map(i => console.log(i.x, i.y));

    console.log(`found ${itemsToLoad.length} \n\n`);
  };
```

Comment: This solution works too but I accepted solution provided by @İlyas-bilgihan because it is more accurate and also it has a way to calculate item visibility percentage (intersectionPercent). Thank you borisdiakur